# Azure DevOps: Pipeline CI/CD - Run all Create sql scripts that are hosted in Synapse Workspace

Tags: azure, azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I have a CI/CD pipeline in Azure Devops that deploys all artifacts to different environments, for example, from dev to acc environment.

And I'm trying to add a code in this pipeline so at the end of deploying, it will run all the Create SQL scripts that I have in the Synapse Workspace.

yml code:

```
    - script: |
    scripts=$(find syn-ws-${{ parameters.environment }} -type f -name 'Create*.sql')
    echo "SQL Scripts to run:"
    echo "$scripts"
    displayName: 'List SQL Scripts to Run'
```

Sql Scripts:

[image]

Another alternative that I'm thinking is create a PS script with Invoke-SqlCmd2 and call that PS script in my pipeline !

Can anyone please help me in achieving this?

Thank you!

Comment: https://github.com/dataplat/Invoke-SqlCmd2

Comment: thanks @rahularyansharma I'll try to create a PS script with Invoke-SqlCmd2 and embed it in my pipeline !